# Using multidimensional arrays to analyze sequences of RNA

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dna-sequence

I'm currently learning about multidimensional arrays and was given the task of analyzing strands of RNA sequences (given from a .txt file). Here is an example of a strand:

> AUGCUUAUUAACUGAAAACAUAUGGGUAGUCGAUGA

Given this string, I am to figure out what protein this RNA strand would create. In order to do so, I am to break down each strand into codons (groups of 3). So for this exampple, I need to look at AUG CUU AUU AAC UGA, etc. Each of these codons represents an amino acid. So AUG is methionine (represented by 'M'), CUU is leucine (represented by 'L') and so on and so forth. My output should therefore be a new string of amino acids (M-L-I...)

What would be the best way to approach this problem? From my understanding, I'm to create a 3-D array, let's say

```
int aminoAcid[4][4][4]
```

Since there are 4 possible choice for each base (A,U,G,C). I'm not entirely sure where to go from here though since certain combinations will give the same amino acid.

EDIT: Am I going in the right direction if a were to first convert the string into number representations (A=0, U=1, G=2, C=3). From there I can work better with a 3d array right?

Comment: What is your goal with the analysis? Do you just start from the beginning and break them into 3, or are the breakpoints something you need to explore with your computation? What exactly is the point of your 3D array? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: @sunny sorry for not being clear. In the end, I need to read out the whole strand and be able to print out a new string of amino acids that sequence represents. There are nuances to it since there are things called stop codons, in which you do print out the following codons until it meets a start codon.

Comment: I don't see where a 3-D array would come into this problem, surely you'd just have a lookup table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 3d array to connect amino acids to different sequences. You should learn about `enum` and figure out how you can use `enum` with your array indices so that you can do something like

```
aminoAcid['A']['U']['G'] = 24
```

where 24 is also corresponding to methionine, meaning you can use another `enum` there. Use `enums` whenever you have a limited known group of items you want to represent with numbers.

It sounds like this is just the beginning of a larger project, so you should follow good practices from the start, thinking about how you can build components that represent your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help and input. I'm not familiar with enum, but would that be the same as changing my original RNA sequence into a string of numbers first? Rather than, aminoAcid['A']['U']['G'] = 24, can i do something like aminoAcid['0']['1']['2'] = 'M', where A=0, U = 1, and G =2?

Comment: That's the idea. Read up on them, and get back to me if you still have questions.